# Nearest Iranian embassy for Canadians

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, iran

Given that neither the [United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93United_States_relations) nor [Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93Iran_relations) have formal diplomatic ties with Iran anymore, that Canadian citizens are required to obtain a [visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Iran) *before* traveling to Iran and can't obtain a [visa on arrival](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Iran#Visa), **where would a Canadian citizen apply for a tourist visa to Iran ?**

Though not a very desirable scenario, I was thinking about getting one in Turkey then going from there, but it seems the Istanbul-Tehran train service is [suspended indefinitely](http://seat61.com/Iran.htm#train). I'd be a bit nervous trying to get a visa from another nearby country as those themselves require visas from Canadians (Azerbaijan, Turkmenistan) or are rather risky (Afghanistan, Iraq).

Is there some arrangement through a third embassy or agency to handle this ? I realize of course it's possible to apply in Mexico, or Europe but would prefer options closer to home.

Comment: Iranians in Canada generally deal with the Iranian Interests Section of the Pakistan Embassy in Washington for consular services, but I don't know whether they deal with tourist visas or not. Note that before you can apply for a tourist visa you need to visit a travel agent to arrange a tour and get an approval code to include with the visa application, and that travel agent will almost certainly know where and how to get the visa and may be able to help with that. If you are trying to get a visa without the tour this may be difficult and the "closest" embassy may not do it.

Comment: @Dennis according to wikivoyage the Iranian section at the Pakistan embassy handles tourist visas but for US citizens

Comment: that could be right, I only know that Iranians in Canada deal with them for passport renewals. A travel agent that does Iran tours will know...

Comment: You know, of course, that it is no longer possible for Canadians to tour Iran independently. You must now be part of an organized tour, same as Americans. The tour operator will help you obtain the visa. If you have dual citizenship, now is the time to use it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had a separate question about that and there were no official references about that rule

Comment: Hmm. I've seen official information to this effect, but Iran seems to not be reachable from here right now, so I'll dig them up later.

Comment: @blackbird57, We have friends in Iran that we've long wanted to visit, but when we explored this 1.5 years ago (after not going in 2012 for another reason) and visited an agency advertising Iran travel they were quite insistent that we needed an approved tour to get a visa. A friend pointed us at another agent they knew in Toronto who could arrange a "fake" tour for us but we decided not to travel that way and gave it up. I've seen no official reference but travel agents are my first stop when it is unclear how to get into a country and in this case they were unanimous about the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer.

The Sultanate of Oman is Iran's Protecting Power in Canada, so the Omani Embassy to Canada would appear to be the appropriate point of contact.

Unfortunately the Omani Embassy to Canada is not in Canada; instead Oman is represented through a non-resident ambassador in the DC office.

As of 2013, according to this news report, the Omanis were not allowed to process visas due to a bureaucratic mess. http://ipolitics.ca/2013/10/24/despite-recent-diplomatic-agreement-iranian-canadians-unable-to-access-consular-services/

It may therefore be best to contact the DC office directly and ask them if they are processing tourist visas.

Comment: As long as you're going to DC you can just talk to the Iranian Interests Section directly.